# Determining conversion rate if users land on specific pages

Tags: google-analytics, conversions

I'm trying to figure out the value of specific pages by finding out if they are more or less likely to convert if they hit certain pages.

For example: I want to know if they are more likely to convert if they hit one of our case studies or if they go to our about page?

Is there a way to do this in Google Analytics? Or do I need secondary software?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this with GA. One way would be to create a custom segment for views of your case study pages and then view your conversions with that segment activated.

You might also want to look into [using funnels](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/conversion-funnel-survival-guide/) on your goal pages. Even without setting them up manually, you can search for 'funnel' within GA to see pages leading to your goal page.